# How to make turtle move continuously without multiple key presses?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making a game where the player gets to move on a line at the bottom of the screen.

At this time to move it the user repeatedly hits the arrow keys, but I want to make it move continuously when the key is pressed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onkeypress(fun, key=None)`

instead of using `onkey()` or `onkeyrelease()`. These two only register the input when the key is released.

`onkeypress(fun, key=None)` registers it while the key is pressed down.

Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) to it in the Turtle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

use the function: `onkeypress`.

here is an example were `onkeypress` is a higher order function:

```
def move_forward():
    t.forward(10)

screen.onkeypress(key='w', fun= move_forward)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the **get_pressed()** function of **key**, [Link](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# Variables
black_background = (0, 0, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 960))
running = True
turtle_image = pygame.image.load('location/to/turtle/image.png')
turtle_rect = turtle_image.get_rect() # Using rect allows for collisions to be checked later
# Set spawn position
turtle_rect.x = 60
turtle_rect.y = 60

while running:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #keys pressed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        turtle_rect.x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        turtle_rect.x += 1

    screen.fill(black_background)
    screen.blit(turtle_image, turtle_rect)
```

Remember, this is just a basic layout and you'll have to read a little more into how you want to accomplish collisions and/or movement with other keys. [Intro Here.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html)

Comment: I stated in the title without pygame

Comment: Also do you know how to get pygame on python 3.6.4 after installation

Comment: @StealthTuba3480 I was able to type 'pip install pygame' and it worked fine. I would uninstall your Python version completely and then download [Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/python-3.6.4.exe) again. As for your question, I misread but it's too ambiguous for me to help. If you're not using the pygame module to write physics and actions for your character movement then what specifically are you using? There are [tons](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries) of game libraries for python you could use. I heard [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) is a lot easier on beginners

Comment: I put in the code that you put before but I get this error: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: Oh you’ll need some initializers as well. I’ll edit my code to update everything you’ll need

Comment: @StealthTuba3480 I updated my comment to give you more insight on how to implement Pygame. There are a few things you'll need to change in my code, such as the image location for the turtle, and remember this is the barebones of what you'd need to run a game.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my turtle-based solution.  It uses a timer to keep the turtle moving at the bottom of the window but lets the timer expire when nothing's happening (turtle has stopped at an edge) and restarts the timer as needed:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def move(new_direction=False):
    global direction

    momentum = direction is not None  # we're moving automatically

    if new_direction:
        direction = new_direction

    if direction == 'right' and turtle.xcor() < width / 2 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        turtle.forward(1)
    elif direction == 'left' and turtle.xcor() > CURSOR_SIZE - width / 2:
        turtle.backward(1)
    else:
        direction = None

    if ((not new_direction) and direction) or (new_direction and not momentum):
        screen.ontimer(move, 10)

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

turtle = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(CURSOR_SIZE - height / 2)
turtle.tilt(90)
turtle.showturtle()

direction = None

screen.onkeypress(lambda: move('left'), "Left")
screen.onkeypress(lambda: move('right'), "Right")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Use the left and right arrows to control the turtle's direction.